# How to write SQLDataSource in Code Behind

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I am new to using ASP.NET and i just want to know how to write the SQLDataSource in Code Behind, I hope you can help me. Thanks in advance.

Here is the code :

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsRecentCases" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:****ConnectionString %>"
    SelectCommand="SELECT TOP 10 C.CASE_KEY, C.DEPARTMENT_CASE_NUMBER, 
    D.DEPARTMENT_NAME, O.OFFENSE_DESCRIPTION AS CHARGE, LAB_CASE, OFFENSE_DATE
    FROM TV_LABCASE C
    INNER JOIN TV_DEPTNAME D ON C.DEPARTMENT_CODE = D.DEPARTMENT_CODE
    INNER JOIN TV_OFFENSE O ON C.OFFENSE_CODE = O.OFFENSE_CODE
    ORDER BY CASE_DATE DESC">
</asp:SqlDataSource>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsDepartment" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:****ConnectionString %>"
    SelectCommand="SELECT [DEPARTMENT_CODE], [DEPARTMENT_NAME] FROM [TV_DEPTNAME]">
</asp:SqlDataSource>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsCharge" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:*****ConnectionString %>"
    SelectCommand="SELECT [OFFENSE_CODE], [OFFENSE_DESCRIPTION] FROM [TV_OFFENSE]">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Code Behind

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string connStr = 
            ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["****ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        drpDepartment.DataSource = dsDepartment;
        drpDepartment.DataTextField = "DEPARTMENT_NAME";
        drpDepartment.DataValueField = "DEPARTMENT_CODE";
        drpDepartment.DataBind();

        drpCharge.DataSource = dsCharge;
        drpCharge.DataTextField = "OFFENSE_DESCRIPTION";
        drpCharge.DataValueField = "OFFENSE_CODE";
        drpCharge.DataBind();

        grdRecentCases.DataSource = dsRecentCases;
        grdRecentCases.DataBind();
    }
```

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ado-net-code-examples

Comment: it is working but i just want to know how can this be written in code behind. can you please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope it may help other people:)

I already formulated the code for C# server-side:

```
        SqlDataSource dsDepartment = new SqlDataSource();
        dsDepartment.ID = "dsDepartment";
        this.Page.Controls.Add(dsDepartment);
        dsDepartment.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        dsDepartment.SelectCommand = "SELECT [DEPARTMENT_CODE], [DEPARTMENT_NAME] FROM [TV_DEPTNAME]";
        drpDepartment.DataSource = dsDepartment;
        drpDepartment.DataTextField = "DEPARTMENT_NAME";
        drpDepartment.DataValueField = "DEPARTMENT_CODE";
        drpDepartment.DataBind();

        SqlDataSource dsCharge = new SqlDataSource();
        dsCharge.ID = "dsCharge";
        this.Page.Controls.Add(dsCharge);
        dsCharge.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        dsCharge.SelectCommand = "SELECT [OFFENSE_CODE], [OFFENSE_DESCRIPTION] FROM [TV_OFFENSE]";
        drpCharge.DataSource = dsCharge;
        drpCharge.DataTextField = "OFFENSE_DESCRIPTION";
        drpCharge.DataValueField = "OFFENSE_CODE";
        drpCharge.DataBind();

        SqlDataSource dsRecentCases = new SqlDataSource();
        dsRecentCases.ID = "dsRecentCases";
        this.Page.Controls.Add(dsRecentCases);
        dsRecentCases.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        dsRecentCases.SelectCommand = "SELECT TOP 10 C.CASE_KEY, C.DEPARTMENT_CASE_NUMBER,D.DEPARTMENT_NAME, O.OFFENSE_DESCRIPTION AS CHARGE, LAB_CASE, OFFENSE_DATE FROM TV_LABCASE C INNER JOIN TV_DEPTNAME D ON C.DEPARTMENT_CODE = D.DEPARTMENT_CODE  INNER JOIN TV_OFFENSE O ON C.OFFENSE_CODE = O.OFFENSE_CODE ORDER BY CASE_DATE";
        grdRecentCases.DataSource = dsRecentCases;
        grdRecentCases.DataBind();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It was a bit hard to understand what you were looking for. If you had asked about creating a SqlDataSource *control* it would have been easy. It's obvious now.